# How does $2N_{h-2}$ become $2^{h/2}$?

Tags: problem-solving

I'm reading the [Lecture 6 notes from MIT OCW Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec06.pdf), which discusses AVL trees, and I'm confused about one of the relations below:

> **Balance:**
>
> Worst when every node differs by 1 -- let $N_h$ = min # nodes in height-*h* AVL tree.
>
> > $\Longrightarrow N_h = N_{h-1} + N_{h-2}+1$
> >
> > $N_h > 2N_{h-2}$
> >
> > $\Longrightarrow N_h > 2^{h/2}$
> >
> > $\Longrightarrow h < 2 \lg N_h$

I don't understand how to arrive at $N_h > 2^{h/2}$ from $N_h > 2N_{h-2}$. In the [lecture video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-6-avl-trees-avl-sort/) (at T27:25), the instructor simply hand-waves it with:

> This looks like two to the something. What's that something? H over two.

Can someone explain the math for that? Thanks.

Comment: Recurse. $N_h > 2 N_{h-2} > 2^2 N_{h-4} > \dots > 2^k N_{h-2k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recursion. Since it is true that $N_h>2\cdot N_{h-2}$ then it is also true that $N_h>2\cdot N_{h-2}>2\cdot2\cdot N_{h-4}$.

Continue like this until you reach $N_h>\underbrace{2\cdot2\cdots2}_{\mathrm{k\, times}}\cdot N_{h-2k}$.

Now, we do this until $k=h/2$ to get $N_h>2^{h/2}N_{0}$.

Comment: $N_0=1$. See [this](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/06sp/handouts/lecture12.pdf) and [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/420/Notes/MountNotes/lecture9-AVL.pdf)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!