# More detailed explanation of how $2N_{h-2}$ becomes $2^{h/2}$?

Tags: induction, problem-solving, recursion

I'm trying to learn the proof of the minimum number of nodes in an AVL tree of height h and I'm stumped on how $2N_{h-2}$ becomes $2^{h/2}$. I've read this [answer]([How does $2N_{h-2}$ become $2^{h/2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809283/how-does-)$2n-h-2$-become-$2h-2)$ and I'm still confused as to why you keep doing this until $k = h/2$.

I understand how $N_h > 2^kN_{h-2k}$. I just am not grasping how that is simplified to $2^{h/2}$. I'm looking for a slightly more detailed answer than the one I linked to. Thanks a lot. Sorry if it's a really stupid question. I bet it's something simple, but it's just flying over my head.

Comment: The answer there says that the next step is to take $k=h/2$, so you get $N_h > 2^{h/2} N_0$.  Does that step make sense?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Not really :/ why is the next step to take k = h/2? Where is that coming from?

Comment: The previous part of the proof establishes $N_h > 2N_{h-2}$.  As you noted, by induction it follows that $N_h > 2^k N_{h-2k}$.  We're using induction here as a formal version of saying "if you do this $k$ times, here's the result".  We take $k=h/2$ because that corresponds to the end of that process.  You extend $N_h > 2N_{h-2} > 2^2N_{h-4} > \dotsb$ until you can't extend it any further.

Comment: Bigger picture: We're trying to get closed-form information about $N_h$ from recursive information about $N_h$.  In this case we can just unroll the recursion until we hit the base case, and then there's no recursion left.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk I get it now! I wasn't realizing that **h/2** was substituted into **k** and that's how it simplifies to **N_0**. And **N_0 = 1** which simplifies to **2^{h/2}**. Thanks I understand it now :]

Comment: I'm new to the math stack exchange and I can't figure out the formatting ha. So sorry for the bad style.

Comment: Formatting tips: use dollar signs for TeX, and use asterisks for emphasis. Thus `$2^{h/2}$` gives $2^{h/2}$; `$$2^{h/2}$$` gives $$2^{h/2} \quad (\textrm{i.e., on a new line});$$ `*2^{h/2}*` gives *2^{h/2}*; and `**2^{h/2}**` gives **2^{h/2}**. See also this very helpful [formatting reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) page.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark Yeah, that's what "take $k=h/2$" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $N_h > 2^kN_{h-2k}$, we want to choose a value of $k$ such that the right-hand-side is constant. That is, we want to reach the initial value $N_0$, which happens when the index $h-2k = 0$, i.e., $k = \frac h2$.